# Python String Reverse Program

Tags: python, string, reverse

I'm trying to write a program that will simply reverse a string. I get an error that something is not subscriptable or something. Could you guys help me pinpoint why this isn't working?

```
listreverse(list1):
     rlist = []
     i = len(list1) - 1
     while i >= 0:
             rlist.append(list[i])
             i = i - 1
     return rlist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rlist.append(list[i])
```

Should be

```
rlist.append(list1[i])
```

Right now you're trying to get the index `i` of the `list` function.

As @gnibbler points out, you should try to pick variable names that are descriptive and distinct enough that you aren't likely to make a typo like this or confuse one variable for another.

Comment: What a simple mistake, thank you!

Comment: It's a good idea to choose variable names that can help avoid those types of mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

your code can be simplified to:

```
def string_reverse(string1):
    return string1[::-1]

print string_reverse('hello')
```

it returns:

```
olleh
```

Note that your code, when takes a string, returns a list, not a string.
Here if you send a string you get the reversed string and if you send a list you get the reversed list

```
print string_reverse([1,2,3,4])
```

returns

```
[4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: This is useful, and I thank you for it, but my class hasn't covered the extended slice syntax yet.

Comment: Then you should tag your question as 'homework'

Comment: nah ... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Comment: @wim, good to know. Not sure about agreeing on the decision. Then, OPs should indicate they don't want to use a given method to solve their problems, even if it is the more idiomatic or simply the best, because their teacher doesn't allow them... Anyway...

Comment: @joaquin Well sorry. I simply asked what was wrong with my program.

Comment: @ThadSmith It's ok, just commenting about the decision on the link given by wim, not about yours: your question was clearly made.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
rlist.append(list[i])
```

To

```
rlist.append(list1[i])
```

That will solve your problem..

There are lots of (other) ways to do that in Python:

```
>>> s = 'Hello World!'
# 1
>>> ''.join(reversed(s))
'!dlroW olleH'
# 2
>>> s[::-1]
'!dlroW olleH'
# 3
>>> r = ''
>>> for i in s:
    r = i+r
>>> r
'!dlroW olleH'
# 4
>>> ''.join(list(s)[::-1])
'!dlroW olleH'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
str='qwerty'
print str[::-1] # it will reverse
```

Comment: I'd recommend formatting your answer to make it more readable